# JDBC manager cannot connect to the database during peak load

Tags: logging, jdbc, log4j

I'm using log4j appender to log some data to the database using JDBC and DataSource, it works perfectly up to certain load but some time when load peaks I get an error saying "JDBC manager cannot connect to the database"

Here's the logs.

> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException Cannot
>   write logging event or flush buffer; JDBC manager cannot connect to
>   the database. at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.connectAndStart(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:95)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.write(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:170)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.append(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:108)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:448)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:433)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:403)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
>   at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146) at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2091)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2005)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1876)
>   at
>   org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.info(AbstractLogger.java:1421)
>   at
>   com.portal.rest.jaxrs.audit.config.AuditLogger.auditLog(AuditLogger.java:62)
>   at
>   com.portal.rest.jaxrs.audit.config.AuditLogger$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a8c1592e.invoke()
>   at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$$Lambda$172.00000000480B3580.proceedWithInvocation(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
>   at
>   com.portal.rest.jaxrs.audit.config.AuditLogger$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f56c2a8f.auditLog()
>   at  com.portal.rest.jaxrs.Document.search(DocumentRes.java:520) at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor246.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508) at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:179)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
>   at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:192) at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:276) at
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:103) at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:96)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:216)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301)
>   at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595) at
>   org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1233)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:782)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:481)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>   at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:121)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterCha

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace (preferably in a code-block). The exception cause will likely show the real reason.

Comment: Hi, mark I have edited it. As I see in logs it gets triggered after calling org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger Log.info() method.

Comment: This is not the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: I have added all the logs I can get. Can check if you can find anything?